# How to find one column in another in sql

Tags: sql

I have a problem with finding one column in another. I have this code:

```
SELECT company.name
FROM company, person
WHERE company.name not like '%'+person.sirname+'%'
```

There are two tables, company with column - name

```
Company of mr. Black
```

and person with column - sirname

```
Black
```

But when I run this code, it becomes an error "invalid number"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings need to be concatenated with the || operator (and you probably need a JOIN condition):

```
SELECT company.name
FROM company, person
WHERE company.name not like '%' || person.sirname || '%'
AND person.company_id = company.id
```

If you use the + operator, the database tries to convert the name into a number and you get the error *invalid number*.

Comment: without AND person.company_id = company.id it should work anyway, because I try to find one column in another, so they should be connected, am i right?

Comment: Without a JOIN condition between the table COMPANY and the table PERSON, each row in the first table is join with each row in the second table and the query result will be huge. Your NOT LIKE condition is hardly a JOIN condition because it eliminates very few rows. So it wouldn't call it *connected. You probably need to better describe the the two tables (columns, sample data) and what exactly you want to achieve (preferrably in a new question). Then we can better help you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are  trying to join the two tables. Try to use the explicit `JOIN` syntax like so:

```
SELECT company.name
FROM company
INNER JOIN person ON company.name not like '%'+person.sirname+'%'
```

Comment: @fen1ksss - What RDBMS you are using?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I think you should use inner join do not for get also to use the IDs I guess this could help If I did not get the question wrong